# Question about Modifier in Java grammar

Tags: java, parsing, grammar, parser-combinators

The Java [grammar](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/syntax.doc.html) defines `ModifiersOpt: { Modifier }`. `Modifier` is defined as one of `public, protected, private, static` etc .... `{x}` denotes zero or more occurrences of `x`.

We know that `public public` is not a valid identifier. Does it mean that any element of the `Modifier` list (e.g. `public`) appears **only once** in `{Modifier}` ? Is there any "standard" parser combinator for `{ Modifier }` ?

Answer (score 2):

Not all errors in a Java program are syntactical errors. An error like `public private` for instance may (as you have discovered) be considered as a semantical error.

As another example, I bet the grammar also allows, for instance

```
int i = "type error";
```

Still though, it is not a valid snippet of Java code.

Comment: That is actually valid Java. (First `i` is a field.)

Answer (score 2):

The modifiers can appear zero or more times.  As [aioobe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759628/question-about-modifier-in-java-grammar/4759682#4759682) said, while syntactically acceptable, `public private` for example is semantically invalid.  There are lots of little situations that are fine strictly according to the grammar but are not allowed by the compiler.

> The grammar below uses the following
>   BNF-style conventions:
>
> {x} denotes zero or more occurrences
>   of x.